# CSRF for Ajax request across applications in one Domain

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, csrf-protection

We have MVC 4 application which is hosted on Web Farm. Site has 5 applications hosted under one domain. These applications communicate with each other. We are implementing Cross Site Request Forgery for our application. We have added AntiForgeyToken(@Html.AntiForgeryToken()) on Layout page. **When we try to post data actions across applications using Ajax request, we are facing below exception-**

**Exception:**
The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the  configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.
For Ajax request we have added  “__RequestVerificationToken” value into prefilter as shown below-

**Client side implementation:**

```js
    $.ajaxPrefilter(function (options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {
    if (options.type.toLowerCase() == "post") {
        if ($('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').length > 0)
            jqXHR.setRequestHeader('__RequestVerificationToken', 
    $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val());
   }});
```

On **Server side** we validated this token as shown below-

```html
string cookie = "";
Dictionary<string, object> cookieCollection = new Dictionary<string, object>();

foreach (var key in HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.AllKeys)
{
cookieCollection.Add(key, (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[key]));
}

var res=  cookieCollection.Where(x => x.Key.Contains("RequestVerificationToken")).First();           

cookie = ((System.Web.HttpCookie)(res.Value)).Value;                                                        
string formToken = Convert.ToString(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]);

if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(formToken))
{
 //To validate HTTP Post request
AntiForgery.Validate();
}
else
{
 //To validate Ajax request
AntiForgery.Validate(cookie, formToken);
}
```

**Other configurations which we have done are as below-**

1. We have machine key in config which is same for all applications as well as on all web servers.
2. We have set AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName = "__RequestVerificationToken" + "_XYZ" cookie name across all applications which is mandatory to access token across applications.

**Changes which we tried to resolve this issue-**

1. We tried to post “__RequestVerificationToken” inside each ajax request’s data so that we can access it using Request.Form but no success on this.
2. We have verified that Content-Type header is appearing with each request.

Please suggest if you have any other way to implement CSRF functionality for Ajax POST requests across multiple applications.